# Typesetting a title on a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to put a title on a `tikzpicture`. In the following code, I put a title on a display within an `axis` environment. This environment is superfluous because I do not want any axes drawn on the display. I want to remove the `axis` environment from my code.

Also, I want to have `A` and `B`, which represent points, and `\ell`, which represents a line, to be typeset in bold in the title. I got an error when using the following code.

`title=An illustration of \boldmath$A$ and $B$\unboldmath \\ being on the same side of \boldmath$\ell$\unboldmath`

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title=An illustration of points $A$ and $B$ \\ being on the same side of $\ell$, title style={align=center,font=\bfseries}
    ]
\end{axis}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\draw[fill] (A) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate (B) at (1.5,2);
\draw[fill] (B) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (A) -- (B);

\coordinate (point_to_label_A) at ($(A)!-7.5pt!(B)$);
\node at (point_to_label_A){$A$};
\coordinate (point_to_label_B) at ($(B)!-7.5pt!(A)$);
\node at (point_to_label_B){$B$};

\coordinate (P) at (-0.75,-1.5);
\coordinate (Q) at (4,2);
\draw[latex-latex] (P) -- (Q);
\coordinate (point_to_label_ell) at ($(Q)!-7.5pt!(P)$);
\node at (point_to_label_ell){$\ell$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is that what you want? I have just used a `node` for the title. No `axis` environment is needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview, border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\draw[fill] (A) circle (1.5pt);
\coordinate (B) at (1.5,2);
\draw[fill] (B) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (A) -- (B);

\coordinate (point_to_label_A) at ($(A)!-7.5pt!(B)$);
\node at (point_to_label_A){$A$};
\coordinate (point_to_label_B) at ($(B)!-7.5pt!(A)$);
\node at (point_to_label_B){$B$};

\coordinate (P) at (-0.75,-1.5);
\coordinate (Q) at (4,2);
\draw[latex-latex] (P) -- (Q);
\coordinate (point_to_label_ell) at ($(Q)!-7.5pt!(P)$);
\node at (point_to_label_ell){$\ell$};

% title
\node[align=center,font=\bfseries, yshift=2em] (title) 
    at (current bounding box.north)
    {An illustration of points $A$ and $B$\\ being on the same side of $\ell$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you put the title at the end you can anchor it using the `current bounding box` special node.

Comment: @percusse Many thanks, nice trick. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @sergej  Your edited code is almost the display that I want.  How do I get `A`, `B`, and `$\ell$` in bold font?  How do you know to use `text width=12cm`?

Comment: @user74973 For bold font, try `$\mathbf{A}$`.

Comment: @user74973 `text width` is not needed, I have removed it.

Comment: @user74973 If you use `align=center` then you can put a manual linebreak in the node text and it will break there.

Comment: @percusse  I appreciate the explanation regarding manually inserting a linebreak in a node.

Comment: @sergej  I posted a similar question at "Typesetting a title on a tikzpicture (Version 2)".  I thought that you may be interested.